# incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__m256d’ from type ‘int’

Tags: c, avx, fma

I'm working on a project to optimize Matrix Multiplication and I'm trying to use intrinsics.

Here's a bit of the code I'm using :

```
#include <immintrin.h>

/* Vector tiling and loop unrolling */
static void do_block(int lda, int M, int N, int K, double* A, double* B, double* C) {
  /* For each row i of A */
  int i, j, k;
  for (i = 0; i < M / 4; ++i) {
    /* For each column j of B */
    for (j = 0; j < N / 12; ++j) {
      register __m256d c_00_03_0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i) * lda + j * 12);
      register __m256d c_00_03_1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i) * lda + j * 12 + 4);
      register __m256d c_00_03_2 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i) * lda + j * 12 + 8);
      register __m256d c_10_13_0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i + 1) * lda + j * 12);
      register __m256d c_10_13_1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i + 1) * lda + j * 12+4);
      register __m256d c_10_13_2 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i + 1) * lda + j * 12+8);
      register __m256d c_20_23_0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i + 2) * lda + j * 12);
      register __m256d c_20_23_1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i + 2) * lda + j * 12+4);
      register __m256d c_20_23_2 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i + 2) * lda + j * 12+8);
      register __m256d c_30_33_0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i + 3) * lda + j * 12);
      register __m256d c_30_33_1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i + 3) * lda + j * 12+4);
      register __m256d c_30_33_2 = _mm256_loadu_pd(C + (4 * i + 3) * lda + j * 12+8);

      /* Loop unrolling */
      for (k = 0; k < K; k += 1) {
    register __m256d b_00_03 = _mm256_loadu_pd(B + k * lda + j * 12);
    register __m256d b_10_03 = _mm256_loadu_pd(B + k * lda + j * 12+4);
    register __m256d b_20_03 = _mm256_loadu_pd(B + k * lda + j * 12+8);
    register __m256d a00 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(A + (4 * i) * lda + k);

    c_00_03_0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_00_03, c_00_03_0);
    c_00_03_1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_10_03, c_00_03_1);
    c_00_03_2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_20_03, c_00_03_2);

    a00 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(A + (4 * i + 1) * lda + k);
    c_10_13_0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_00_03, c_10_13_0);
    c_10_13_1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_10_03, c_10_13_1);
    c_10_13_2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_20_03, c_10_13_2);

    a00 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(A + (4 * i + 2) * lda + k);
    c_20_23_0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_00_03, c_20_23_0);
    c_20_23_1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_10_03, c_20_23_1);
    c_20_23_2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_20_03, c_20_23_2);

    a00 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(A + (4 * i + 3) * lda + k);
    c_30_33_0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_00_03, c_30_33_0);
    c_30_33_1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_10_03, c_30_33_1);
    c_30_33_2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a00, b_20_03, c_30_33_2);
      }
}
}
```

All the lines using the function __mm256_fmadd_pd throw the following error :

`incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__m256d’ from type ‘int’`

I'm not sure where the int comes from because all the arguments of `__mm256_madd_pd` are "`__m256d`" and the return value is also "`__m256d`" `(__m256d _mm256_fmadd_pd (__m256d a, __m256d b, __m256d c))`

Comment: After closing some `}` this compiles fine with gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/s5has7. Nevertheless, I would recommend to get rid of all `register` keywords. The compiler should know better what to put in registers and what not (and you need to check what actually happens, anyway).

Comment: I still can't figure out how Am I getting the error while using my local compiler (gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)) and not getting it in godbolt.org even though I used the same compiler and the same flags (-march=native)

Comment: What is `native` in your case? Does `cat /proc/cpuinfo` include FMA?

Comment: I didn't find FMA with `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "fma"` . If that's what causing the problem, there's no fix for it since the CPU doesn't support FMA, right ?

Comment: That means your CPU does not support FMA. You could compile with `-mfma`, but this would fail at runtime.

Comment: The workaround would of course be to call `_mm256_add_pd(_mm256_mul_pd(aXX, bYY), cZZ)` (you can put that into an inline function).

Comment: Were there more errors or warnings besides "incompatible types"?  If you don't have FMA, then I think `-march=native` would set `#defines` so that  `_mm256_fmadd_pd` was not declared by the header files.  You would get an "implicit declaration" warning and it would be implicitly declared as returning `int`, which would then explain the "incompatible types" error.  But it would be the "implicit declaration" that would be the cause of it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by chtz, the processor I'm using does not support FMA functions as `_mm256_fmadd_pd` so I used the workaround he proposed that works just fine :
 `_mm256_add_pd(_mm256_mul_pd(aXX, bYY), cZZ)`